# AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding encrypt in java decrypt in python goes wrong

Tags: java, python, aes, padding, pkcs#5

I'm trying to encrypt a data file in a Java and then decrypt in Python.

but the decrypted data file always got some padding bytes remainslike this

```
my normal content^@^@^@^@^@
```

I actually do the UNPAD action in the python code ( func decrypt_file() )

and when I remove the UNPAD action, I got this:

```
my normal content^@^@^@^@^@^P^P^P^P^P^P^P^P^P^P^P^P^P^P^P^P
```

SO, It seems that the Java encrypt method did padding TWICE.

I'm so confused and stuck here. Can anybody help? Thanks a lot!

Here is my code.

(1) java version

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class AESUtil {
    private static final String key = "wesurexZ5!Hcurfit";
    private static final String ivs = "zK2hzBvP%FRJ5%lD";
    public static byte[] encrypt(byte[] strInBytes) throws Exception {
        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = getKey(key);
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(ivs.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, iv);
        return cipher.doFinal(strInBytes);
    }

    public static byte[] decrypt(byte[] strIn) throws Exception {
        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = getKey(key);
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(ivs.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, iv);
        byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(strIn);
        return decrypted;
    }

    private static SecretKeySpec getKey(String strKey) throws Exception {
        byte[] arrBTmp = strKey.getBytes();
        byte[] arrB = new byte[16];
        for (int i = 0; i < arrBTmp.length && i < arrB.length; i++) {
            arrB[i] = arrBTmp[i];
        }
        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(arrB, "AES");
        return skeySpec;
    }
}
```

(2) python version

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys

reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8")

from Crypto.Cipher import AES


class AESTool(object):

    def __init__(self, iv, key):
        self.iv = iv.decode("utf8")
        self.key = key
        bs = AES.block_size
        self.pad = lambda s: s + (bs - len(s) % bs) * chr(bs - len(s) % bs)
        self.unpad = lambda s: s[0:-ord(s[-1])]

    def encrypt(self, plain_text):
        try:
            encryptor = AES.new(self.key, AES.MODE_CBC, self.iv)
            encrypted_text = encryptor.encrypt(self.pad(plain_text))
        except Exception as ex:
            raise Exception(ex.message)

        return encrypted_text

    def decrypt(self, decrypted_text):
        try:
            decryptor = AES.new(self.key, AES.MODE_CBC, self.iv)
            plain_text = decryptor.decrypt(decrypted_text)
        except Exception as ex:
            raise Exception(ex.message)

        return self.unpad(plain_text)

    def encrypt_file(self, from_full_path, to_full_path, chunksize=64*1024):
        encryptor = AES.new(self.key, AES.MODE_CBC, self.iv)
        try:
            with open(from_full_path, 'rb') as infile:
                with open(to_full_path, 'wb') as outfile:
                    while True:
                        chunk = infile.read(chunksize)

                        if len(chunk) == 0:
                            break

                        if len(chunk) < chunksize:
                            outfile.write(encryptor.encrypt(self.pad(chunk)))
                            break

                        outfile.write(encryptor.encrypt(chunk))
        except Exception as ex:
            return -1

        return 0

    def decrypt_file(self, from_full_path, to_full_path, chunksize=64*1024):
        decryptor = AES.new(self.key, AES.MODE_CBC, self.iv)
        try:
            with open(from_full_path, 'rb') as infile:
                with open(to_full_path, 'wb') as outfile:
                    prev_chunk = None
                    while True:
                        chunk = infile.read(chunksize)

                        if len(chunk) == 0 and prev_chunk:
                            outfile.write(self.unpad(decryptor.decrypt(prev_chunk)))
                            break

                        if prev_chunk:
                            outfile.write(decryptor.decrypt(prev_chunk))

                        if len(chunk) < chunksize:
                            outfile.write(self.unpad(decryptor.decrypt(chunk)))
                            break

                        prev_chunk = chunk
        except Exception as ex:
            return -1

        return 0
```

Comment: The IV needs to be random and different for each encryption.

Comment: @zaph I just knew reusing a fixed IV could cause security issues. But how could that brings functionality problems like this? I don't quite get it, could u please fill me in? Thank you very much.

Comment: The comment was not just for the OP but for future readers, pointing out that  the fixed IV in the question is poor security.

Comment: @RonnieTsang : what is the value for iv in the case of python code ?

Answer (score -1):

Do you know if this happens when you just try and enc/dec using the default modes? Curious to know because if that is the case then we are having the same issue. What I mean by default is using:

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
```

Instead of;

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
```

Comment: thank for your info. I didn't know default modes could have extractly the same issue previously. But surely encrypt/decrypt aross different platform could result in uncertainty padding-relevant issues. I am seeking a across-platform way to use aes, and I found [aes-cross](https://github.com/keel/aes-cross). the author's conclusion is "If you find a way to AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding on a platform, you have already got the cross-platform AES solution on it." So comes my code above

Comment: It is always best to fully specify the encryption attributes such as mode and padding.